# How do you hook a server side Logout function to ASP.Net Authentication Service Logout

Tags: asp.net, authentication, service

The Asp.net AJAX authentication service provides Login and Logout methods. I can configure a membership provider and a client side call to Login will call my server side ValidateUser defined in the membership provider. All good so far.

However, the Logout method issues a call to the built-in service's Logout method which basically set the ASPXAUTH cookie to nothing.

How do I hook into this call and write a server function that does a few housekeeping stuff when the Authentication service Logout is called?

TIA

Answer (score 1):

The AJAX auth wraps Forms Authentication, so this question is the best you'll probably get [Event to capture when a formsauthenticated user is un-authenticated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/480681/event-to-capture-when-a-formsauthenticated-user-is-un-authenticated)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot override [LogOut()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff423315%28v=vs.91%29.aspx) method in the [AuthenticationBase](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff422449%28v=vs.91%29.aspx) class, but you can override [ClearAuthenticationToken()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff423161%28v=vs.91%29.aspx) method instead. You can do any server side logic there. If you need a user name use [GetUser()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff422990%28v=vs.91%29.aspx) method.

Answer (score -2):

Maybe the Session_End event in Global.asax can be of help to you:
http://www.codetoad.com/asp.net_globalasax.asp

Comment: Session_End is not guaranteed to fire